# Can't use Firestore timestamp('toDate' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore in React. And this application saves `created_at` datetime as Timestamp object to Firestore like below. use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

```
export function createComment(uid, values, count) {
  return dispatch => {
    commentsRef
      .add({
        uid: uid,
        content: values.content,
        created_at: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      })
      .then(function() {
        roomsRef
          .doc(uid)
          .update({
            comment_count: Number(count) + 1
          })
          .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: CREATE_COMMENT });
          });
      });
  };
}
```

But the error occurs when I tried to display `created_at` Timestamp.

```
// Fetch comments
export function fetchComments(uid) {
  return dispatch => {
    commentsRef
      .where("uid", "==", uid)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        const comments = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          return {
            const timstamp = doc.data().created_at.toDate();
            // error occurs
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
            timestamp: timestamp
          };
        });
        return comments;
      })
      .then(comments => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_COMMENTS, payload: comments });
      });
  };
}
```

error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined

Timestamp is successfully fetched though.

[image]

Comment: That object you return from the map doesn't look like it calls toDate().  It seems to try to call a method called Date().  Are you missing something here?

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson Sorry for my mistake. I can't do that with `toDate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`created_At` is an object, as you have clearly shown in the log. If you want to convert it to a date then pick one of the fields. So `created_at.nanoseconds` will give you a timestamp you can convert.

I'm not sure what `toDate()` is, that's not a native js method, are you referring moment js? If you want to convert a timestamp into a date you should try `new Date(created_at.nanoseconds)`

Comment: I did {created_at.nanoseconds} but `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nanoseconds' of undefined` error occurs.

Comment: I think you are calling the `toDate()` functin before the data arrives. Try `const timstamp = doc.data() && doc.data().created_at && doc.data().created_at.toDate();` to ensure you only call teh method once teh data exists. If it doesn't work can you show us where yo are logging `created_at` as you said  it is successfully fetched.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!!